# GCP Pubsub causing concurrency issue

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, concurrency

So my problem is like this:

I have a topic say T1, we've added a Pull Subscription PS1 in our application.
Our application is deployed to a K8s cluster which can extend upto 5 pods or say n pods.

So the problem i'm facing is, there's a message M1, which should get processed by P1 as it got consumed by it first, but we see that M1 is being processed by P1,P2,P3.. as well, so why are all the pods picking up the same message?

How to avoid this?

Comment: Have you only one subscription or your pod also create a subscription to the topic?

Comment: I can think of couple possible reasons:
 - message is not acknowledged at the end of processing;
 - message is acknowledged after the ackDeadline.
In both cases message will become available in the subscription for duplicated processing after the ackDeadline.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have one subscription, i believe multiple pods act like subscribers to the same subscription at same time.

Comment: @OleksandrBushkovskyi let's say I will have 5 minuted ackDeadline, but isn't it possible for other pods to subscribe to that message again in parallel within that 5 minutes time span? Or once a subscriber processes the message, others can't?

Comment: Yes, once subscriber receives the message, other subscribers to the same subscription won't receive it during the ackDeadline span.

Comment: The only reason to consume the same message, in the same time is to have several subscription. If you have only one subscription, the message is delivered to one and only one subscriber at a time. However, if the message is nack (timeout or explicit nack) it returns to the message pool and can be delivered to another subscriber. but it's not concurrent it's subsequent.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry for late reply, but we've configured only 1 subscriber on that topic, and thing is multiple pods are attempting to process it even before the first delivery attempt has returned an Ack or Nack.. I also see the delivery attempt count is also increasing.

Comment: @OleksandrBushkovskyi it is doing :(, the the reply in the answer posted below. explained the scenario there.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/things-i-wish-i-knew-about-google-cloud-pub-sub-part-2-b037f1f08318), maybe you need to modify the acknowledgement deadline in order to give more time the client to acking

> “A predetermined amount of time (this defaults to 10 seconds) is
> allocated for the client to acknowledge (ack) this message before the
> server redelivers it. This is known as the acknowledgement deadline.
> If the client holds the message beyond the agreed deadline without
> acking, or if the client sends a Nack (negative acknowledged) request,
> the message will be redelivered (potentially to a different subscriber
> if you have multiple set up).

> Sometimes, the acknowledgement deadline
> is not enough time for a message to be ack’ed by the client, so a
> ModifyAckDeadline request is used to extend the deadline.”

In that case you need to apply concurrency control, concurrency control allows you to configure how many threads or streams are used by the client library to pull messages. Increasing the number of threads or streams allows your client to pull messages from the Pub/Sub server more rapidly. The C++, Go, Java, Ruby clients let you configure how many threads are used for callbacks, though some clients, like Node, don’t support this. Increasing the number of callback threads allows you to process more messages concurrently.

In [this Link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publisher-concurrency-control#pubsub_publisher_concurrency_control-java) you will find a code sample to configure a publisher to have different numbers of threads for publishing messages and processing message futures.

If you want to know more about [Ordering Messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering) or have [Subscribe Overview](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber).

Comment: Ack deadline is set as 600 secs(5 minutes), but pods are picking up in parallel the same message even before the first pod has even acked/nacked. 
Eg. Pod1 picked at 18:00:00 utc, and end at 18:04:00 utc, but meanwhile this is going on, we see in logs that another pod has picked up the same event with delivery attempt count as 2 and it started at 18:02:00 utc..

Comment: @AkashBeura might it be that you have duplicates in your subscription? Are you logging "messageId" attribute, to be sure that it's exactly the same message?